# To remove rendering of menus and header, plugin or theme?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, views

I need to create a view of my website which does not render the header (where I see my user name) and maybe display just one menu on the side.
Do I achieve this through a plugin or through creating a new theme?

Comment: Create a [Page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) and do whatever.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, It is part of the theme mechanism. So I do this as part of writing my site theme, right?

Comment: Yes, you got me correct.

Comment: you better delete the answer, because it's a basic one, and everyone knows it.

Comment: LOL everybody is about 7 billion people I am sure most of them do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a Page Template is a much simpler way of alternating Page views, creating one is nice and easy:

- Simply copy the `page.php` in your theme, and paste it.
- Rename the file to anything, best practice is: `page-template-something.php`
- Put the following code into the file at the very top:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: My Design
 */

//get_header(); //or do whatever
```

- Now you can remove everything from the page and redesign however you like.

Copying the existing `page.php` will give a guide on page structure, you can follow that or can create your entirely new view.

#### More details:

- [**Page Templates** - WordPress Developer Guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)